# Filter list of list column then split (explode) row-wisely in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have one column in a dataframe which has list of list:

```
   id                                                pos
0   1  [[['Malaysia','NR'], [':','PU'], ['Natural','JJ'], ['selling price','NN']]]
1   2  [[['Spot Price','NN'], [':','PU'], ['cotton','NN'], ['India', ' NR']]]
```

or in dictionary format:

```
[{'id': 1,
  'pos': "[[['Malaysia','NR'], [':','PU'], ['Natural','JJ'], ['selling price','NN']]]"},
 {'id': 2,
  'pos': "[[['Spot Price','NN'], [':','PU'], ['cotton','NN'], ['India', ' NR']]]"}]
```

How could I filter if second element of list is `NR` or `NN` then split (explode) `pos` column row-wisely as follows:

```
   id          words part_of_speech
0   1        Malasia             NR
1   1  selling price             NN
2   2     Spot price             NN
3   2         cotton             NN
4   2          India             NR
```

How could I acheive this in Python? Thanks.

Trial code:

```
l = [[['Malaysia','NR'], [':','PU'], ['Natural','JJ'], ['selling price','NN']]]
for elem in l[0]:
    print(elem[1])
```

Out:

```
NR
PU
JJ
NN
```

Comment: can you share this as a dictionary: ``df.to_dict('records')``

Comment: Sure, sorry about that, I updated, pls check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this with `explode`:

```
x = df.explode('pos').explode('pos')
x = x[['id']].reset_index(drop=True).join(pd.DataFrame(x['pos'].tolist()).set_axis(['words', 'part_of_speech'], axis=1))
x.loc[x['part_of_speech'].isin(['NN', 'NR'])]
```

---

```
   id          words part_of_speech
0   1       Malaysia             NR
3   1  selling price             NN
4   2     Spot Price             NN
6   2         cotton             NN
7   2          India             NR
>>>
```

This is solution could be scaled easily for dataframes with arbitrary length, it doesn't assign columns one by one, it assigns columns at once. So it would work for arbitrary length sublists.

Comment: This should raise an error on the first line, `str` works only on Series, also going through a DataFrame constructor should be slower (no need to plan for upscaling if there won't be upscaling) ;)

Comment: @mozway Ah yes! edited my answer sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution, it explodes first and filters afterwards, which I believe should be more efficient as it doesn't require looping:

```
# get rid of unnecessary level of nesting
df['pos'] = df['pos'].str[0]
# explode the list
df = df.explode('pos')
# split the two items to separate columns
df['words'] = df['pos'].str[0]
df['part_of_speech'] = df['pos'].str[1]
# filter output
df.drop('pos', axis=1)[df['part_of_speech'].isin(['NR', 'NN'])]
```

Output:

```
   id          words part_of_speech
0   1       Malaysia             NR
0   1  selling price             NN
1   2     Spot Price             NN
1   2         cotton             NN
```